# Jest throws error Unexpected token function when trying to import component

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a basic react component with Jest, but it breaks when I try to import the component. EDIT: Noticed that it doesnt throw this error if I load in a more simple component. The one I am trying to load in is basically the same but has an `async` instance method. Perhaps that is what is breaking jest?

test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Component from '../components/component';


describe('Component', () => {

    it('renders the player component', () => {

        expect(true).toBe(true)

    });


});
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

package.json jest config:

```
"jest": {

    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js",

    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx"
    ],

    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Do you use mocha?

Comment: @Roman nope just trying to use Jest/Enzyme

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't know that Jest is its own test runner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably right in your assumption about the `async` keyword breaking the test. If you are running this tests in a lower version of NodeJS than v7.6, [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is not supported by the presets you are using in the `.babelrc` file.

You need one of these presets / plugins:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/
- https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env with the correct settings
- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/